# mysql query , "sending data" error on not so complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My data is like

```
| order_id  |  user_id  |     ip      |
---------------------------------------
| 1001      |   2       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1002      |   5       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1003      |   2       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1004      |   12      |   18.15.0.1 |    
| 1005      |   9       |    10.0.0.1 |  

SELECT "ip", user_id
FROM userlog
WHERE "ip" IN (
    SELECT "ip"
    FROM userlog
    GROUP BY "ip"
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
GROUP BY "ip"
ORDER BY "id" DESC
```

When I run this query on my desktop I get results within 1 second, but when I run this same query on production server, query hangs for hours with message sending data, populating temp table...
Why is this query giving me so much trouble and how to scale it so i can run it avoiding this sending data problem?

Comment: Why don't you put "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" on the main query instead of creating a subquery for this?? The way I see it you'll get the same that with much less trouble. I think it should help if you get rid of the subquery.

Comment: I am trying this right now but it's even slower, it takes 2.5s on my desktop

Comment: Is the field "ip" indexed? that would also hope.

Comment: no there is none indexed fields

Comment: when i put index on ip column, query takes longer than without index

Answer (score 0):

Try a self join instead, something like:

```
SELECT u1."ip", u1.user_id
FROM userlog u1
JOIN userlog u2
    ON u1.ip = u2.ip and u1.order_id <> u2.order_id
ORDER BY u1."id" DESC
```

Comment: this query never ends, it hangs with message "sending data". I have 245800 total rows to read from table

Comment: @John, how much result data is expected?

Comment: I don't understand the question? I would like to get just duplicate users which are using same ip address.

Comment: i would like to get result like this
userids                      ip                 date
3750,5178  192.168.2.12  03-09-17